# Complex graph Entropy Measure in R

Tags: r, function, igraph, shortest-path

For this Measure i would always only need the incoming Tree into a Vertex.
First Part i would have to calculate all shortest Path to a Vertex, And Sum them up in a special Way, all with a shortestPath=1 Would count as 1 all with a shortestPath=2 would count as 1/2, all with shortestPath=3 as 1/3 and so on. Then they should be summed up to a Value which we now call x.
After this is done for the complete Graph, there should be a function which would take x and calculate
 x/sum(y) y would be all calculated Values from above minus the one we are currently Working on.

My initial Data is:

```
library(igraph)
From <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
To <- c(NA,1,2,3,2,NA,6,7)
Data <- data.frame(From,To)
Network <- graph.data.frame(Data[,c("From","To")],directed=TRUE)
Network<- Network - "NA"
plot(Network)
```

[image]

At the end it should look like similar to this

```
From <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
To <- c(NA,1,2,3,2,NA,6,7)
ValueX<- c(2.333, 2.5, 1, 0, 0, 1.5, 1, 0)
FinalMeasure<- c(2.333/(2.5+1+0+0), 2.5/(2.333+1+0+0), 1/(2.333+2.5+0+0), 0/(2.333+2.5+1+0), 0/(2.333+2.5+1+0), 1.5/(1+0), 1/(1.5+0), 0/(1.5+1))
NewData<- data.frame(From,To, ValueX, FinalMeasure)
```

My first Idea was to build a function with clusters() and shortest.paths() but i have no idea how i could do it.

Comment: The question should show that you made a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself and are not just asking people to write the code for you. It's very nice to have the sample input and desired output, that will make it much easier to test possible solutions, but what have you tried so far? Can you share some of the code of your attempt and be clear about what went wrong? Also, i assume you mean the `igraph` library, rather than `graph`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you can calculate `ValueX` and `FinalMeasure` with this code

```
pp <- 1/shortest.paths(Network, mode="out")
pp[!is.finite(pp)]<-0
ValueX <- colSums(pp)

FinalMeasure <- ave(dd, clusters(Network)$membership, FUN=function(x) x/(sum(x)-x))
```

So your final table is

```
NewData<- data.frame(From,To, ValueX, FinalMeasure)

#   From To   ValueX FinalMeasure
# 1    1 NA 2.333333    0.6665714
# 2    2  1 2.500000    0.7500750
# 3    3  2 1.000000    0.2069108
# 4    4  3 0.000000    0.0000000
# 5    5  2 0.000000    0.0000000
# 6    6 NA 1.500000    1.5000000
# 7    7  6 1.000000    0.6666667
# 8    8  7 0.000000    0.0000000
```